# How to get which commands are applyed on rich text box, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple RichText Editor which contains standard operations (Bold|Italic|Underline, Text Alignment, Font type, color and size). I am using execCommand function in JavaScript (more [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands)). So the command buttons are toggle buttons and when the mouse pointer is on the bold text (for example) how to make toggle button pressed. With other words - Has anyone idea how to get applied commands on the text to change the toggle button states. If I am not sufficiently detailed, ask me.
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: post some codes. It'll be easier to solve the question

Comment: Thats a simple example of my text box:
http://jsbin.com/oriveg/3/edit

Comment: @ValKirilov: Buttons elements aren't toggleable. Buttons that are displayed as being locked on pressed state (for e.g.: on/off) are actually `DIV` elements with borders or a background image.

Comment: Toggle buttons aren't my problem, my part of the question is how to get applied commands on selected text to do my job with buttons..